# BTRFS suboptimal multi-disk allocation

Tags: btrfs

I have a BTRFS Raid 1, with the following `btrfs fi show`:

```
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 1.45TiB
    devid    7 size 698.64GiB used 694.15GiB path /dev/bcache32
    devid    9 size 931.51GiB used 928.51GiB path /dev/bcache0
    devid   10 size 698.64GiB used 694.64GiB path /dev/bcache48
    devid   11 size 1.82TiB used 697.00GiB path /dev/bcache16
```

From here, you can see that the three smaller devices are almost full (in fact, they were completely full just a while ago, giving me `ENOSPC` errors). However, the larger 2TB HDD is mostly empty.

The volume is "full" because any data added to the 2 TB disk must also be mirrored on the other disks, but they're all full. Ideally, I'd be able to move copies from the smaller disks to the 2 TB disk so I'd have room to add more data later.

A full `btrfs balance` seems to juggle the data around but doesn't actually make significant changes to the allocation proportions.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How would raid-1 mirroring help you if both copies of your data were on the same disk?

Comment: @JeffSchaller that's exactly the problem. BTRFS won't allocate the copy to the same disk. However, there's no space on any other disk, so the redundancy cannot be satisfied, hence `ENOSPC`. Ideally, I'd move some of the copies from the smaller disks to to the larger one so the distribution would be less skewed.

Comment: I tried messing with `btrfs resize`, but at a given point BTRFS just refuses to put the relocated blocks on the larger device, for some reason.